# Sitefinity Performance - Minimizing loaded ScriptResources

Tags: performance, sitefinity, scriptresource.axd

I am trying to make a Sitefinity site run faster by minizing the requests sent to the server especially the amount of ScriptResource.axd files loaded in the page.

[image: ScriptResources]

Is these files are all required to be loaded for a fairly simple Sitefinity page?

How can we minimize or even combine these scripts to improve performance?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

regards,

Joseph

Comment: What version of Sitefinity are you on? Are you logged in as an admin when checking the resources? Sitefinity loads a lot of resource files used by the editing tools overlay.

Comment: Hi Ben, I am using Sitefinity 6.x and these resources are from a Front End Page in Sitefinity and not backend. I ended up using the RadScriptManager to combine these Resources into one single file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to make it run faster is by enabling the **Client Cache** mode from Sitefinity's settings.

You go to **Administration->Settings->Advanced->System->Output cache settings** then you check the '**Enable Client Cache**' check box.

If the "Default Output Cache Profile" on the same section is set to "Standard Caching" then you can go two levels deeper in the settings tree to "**Client Cache Profile-> Standard Caching**" and set the the expiring time duration in seconds in "**Duration**" field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Radoslav. I ended up using Telerik RadScriptManager to combine all the Resource files.